# jQuery onChange doesn't trigger when you clear input[type=file] value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to do an operation when the file is changed or when we clear the file input.

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
       console.log('changed')
});
```

It works when I select/change the file.

It doesn't trigger change event when I clear the input[type=file].

```
$('input[type="file"]').val('');
```

Does clearing the value triggers the change event? or what would be a better way to this?

Comment: If you are programmatically clearing the value like the above example, you can just call $('input[type="file"]').trigger("change"); right after that value is cleared.

Comment: Or better yet, just directly call the `change` callback.

Comment: @Asyranok Yes, this can be done. So clearing the input doesn't trigger change event? Need to explicitly trigger the 'change' event. right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force to trigger the event change

```
 $('input[type="file"]').val('').trigger('change');
```

Comment: @ejaz Does this one liner works for you?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar yes it works. I figured it out that it `val('')` doesn't trigger 'change' event. Have to trigger the event by `$('input[type="file"]').val('').trigger('change');` or `$('input[type="file"]').val('').change();`

Comment: @ejaz Ah, thanks for letting it me know. I was having something else in mind.